# Find which ports a program access

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, netstat

I have a program that tries to connect to a server on start-up on a unknown port. I need to find out which port the program accesses to enable a ssh tunnel.

I tried `netstat` but since the connection fails I don't find any useful information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
strace -e trace=connect -f yourprogram
```

or using a dump file

```
strace -o yourprogram.strace -e trace=connect -f yourprogram
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option: the `auditd` of Linux support system call logging.

`sudo auditctl -a entry,always -F arch=b64 -S connect`

Something better compare to `strace`: you can filter by multiple condition.

For example:

- Audit/Log all failed `connect` system call: `sudo auditctl -a entry,always -F arch=b64 -F success!=0 -S connect`
- Audit/Log all `connect` system call by specific uid: `sudo auditctl -a entry,always -F arch=b64 -F auid=501 -S connect`